# Rectangular barrier embedded in Infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, linear-algebra

Consider the problem:

> Let a particle be subjected to the following 1-dimensional potential:
> $$
> V(x) = \begin{cases} 
>           V_0 > 0 & 0 \leq x < b \\
>           0 & b < x < a \\
>           +\infty & a < x 
>        \end{cases}
> $$
> which is extended to the real line by requiring it to be even ($V(x) = V(-x)$).
> Find the values of $V_0$ and $b$ such that the least energy eigenvalue $E_0$ is equal to $V_0$.

I have tried solving the problem as follows:

- I wrote the *time-indipendent Schrodinger equation*:
  $$ ( (E-V(x)) + \partial_x^2 ) u_E(x) = 0 $$
- I required $E = V_0$ so that I could find necessary conditions for the existence of an energy eigenvalue which is equal to $V_0$
- I solved the equation in each subinterval in which $V(x)$ is constant, thus finding three distinct solutions with two arbitrary constants each
- I required the solutionto be continuous at $x=\pm b$ (boundary conditions) and continuously differentiable at $x=\pm a$ (definition of solution to the equation) thus finding a linear system of $6$ indipendent equations in $6$ variables (namely the constants)
- finally I computed the determinant of the system and I required it to be equal to $0$ (in order to have non trivial solutions) but I couldn't find any close-form condition on either $b$ or $V_0$

Since this exercise was taken from an exam I am reasonably sure that you should find a closed form solution. Also, I know that what I did was just requiring the existence of an energy eigenvalue which is equal to $V_0$ while ignoring that I also need it to be the least one. Should I try doing the exercise again but this time without requiring $E=V_0$? Is my reasoning correct?

---

As always, any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Answer (score 1):

The boundary condition  at the hard walls is $\psi(\pm a)=0$, thats the conventional definition of the selfadjoint restriction of the operator $\partial_{x,x}$ on Hilbert space $\mathit L^2((-a,a), dx)$,   yielding symmetry $\int_{-a}^a g f'' dx = \int_{-a}^a g'' f dx$

Comment: Yes, I know and I have imposed it.

Answer (score 1):

A priori, there is no reason for $V_0$ to be in the spectrum, on the contrary, it should not be for small values. Indeed, as $V_0\to 0$, you recover the infinite well which has a finite zero point energy.

Secondly, there is no reason to have a closed form expression of the spectrum. Indeed, even in the simplified case where $a\to\infty$ and $V_0<0$, the pothole, the spectrum has no explicit form in terms of the usual functions. Your determinant equation will still give you an implicit expression of the spectrum. Even if you cannot solve it explicitly, you can always extract information, and for special cases of $a,b,V_0$ recover asymptotics.

Btw a faster way to get the spectrum is to use the parity symmetry of the potential and look for odd and even eigenfunctions. For each case, this gives you only three unknowns and three coupled linear equations (two for $x=b$ and one for $x=a$).

Hope this helps.